# Understanding exceptions in Java with interfaces

Tags: java, oop, interface

I have the following code which has two interfaces which have two methods of the same name. However each method throws a different type of Exception.

```
public interface xyz {
void abc() throws IOException;
}
public interface qrs {
void abc() throws FileNotFoundException;
}
public class Implementation implements xyz, qrs {
// insert code
{ /*implementation*/ }
}
```

I know that in inheritance if a subclass method overrides a superclass method, a subclass's throw clause can contain a subset of a superclass's throws clause and that it must not throw more exceptions. However, I am not sure how exceptions are dealt with in interfaces.

For the implementation of the function `abc()` in the class `Implementation`, can this method throw both of the exceptions or just one? For example, is the following method valid?

```
public void abc() throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
```

Any insights are appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you try?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A class that implements an interface must satisfy all of the requirements of that interface. One requirement is a negative requirement--a method must not throw any checked exceptions except those declared with a `throws` clause on that interface.

`FileNotFoundException` is a specific kind (subclass) of `IOException`, so if your `Implementation` class declares `void abc() throws FileNotFoundException`, it satisfies the requirements of both `qrs` (which permits only that specific exception) and `xyz` (which permits any kind of `IOException`). The inverse is not true, however; if it says that it `throws IOException`, it doesn't meet the contract of `qrs`.

Comment: Just to clarify, is the contract of qrs the fact that if an implementing class has the method abc() it must throw the FileNotFoundException?

Comment: @ceno980 No, that's what I meant by *negative requirement*; the implementing class *may* throw `FileNotFoundException`, but it *must not* throw any other checked exceptions. An implementation that declared no throws clause at all would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

They do not have to throw the exceptions of an interface.
Your function may not throw exceptions that were not in the interface.